# Trouble with jQuery UI layout and jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-layout

I am trying to create a layout structured like this:

- north pane
- center pane

  - a header div
  - a notebook-like tab panel

    - with at least one tab
  - a footer div

header div and footer div has to be always visible,
the tab should take all remaining space and should have
a vertical scroll bar if needed.

Here is what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/mguijarr/y57v3nkf/

I set `overflow:hidden` on the center pane, I tried to set
`height: 100%` on tab panel for it to grow as much as it can,
but it's eating the space below (ie. the footer div is not
shown).

What can I do to fix the layout ?

Answer (score 1):

The footer is there. The problem is just that you can't set the `div#tabs` with height: 100%, because the outer div has `overflow:hidden`

It will have the same height as its container, but as the footer is at the same level as the `div#tabs`, it will be hidden, because the `div.ui-layout-center` has the `overflow:hidden`.

First solution: change the height of `div#tabs` to a lower percentage:

```
   <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; height: 100px; background: #ffff00;"></div>
   <div id="tabs" style="height: 40%; overflow: auto">
        content
   </div>
   <div style="background: #ff0000; height: 100px; ">footer</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y57v3nkf/1/

Second solution, change the overflow option of the outer div to automatic:
https://jsfiddle.net/y57v3nkf/2/

Third Solution (Jquery Brute force):
Set the outer div to 100% height, and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var outerDivHeight = $('div.ui-layout-center').height();
   var tabDivHeight = outerDivHeight - 100 - 100 -10;

   $('#tabs').height(tabDivHeight);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y57v3nkf/3/

Porblems with this solution:

- You have to do calculations.
- It gets the correct height when page
  loads, but then it doesn't if the page is resized.

TIP: Go percentual:
These layouts get really tricky when you have fixed size divs along with percentual divs. To go fully responsive, you'll have to redo all the layout thinking in percentages, example:

```
|-------------100%-----------------|
|---20%----|------------80%--------|
|....|.....|.....|.................|
```

Comment: thanks for the help. solution 2 is not what I am looking after, since it adds a vertical scrollbar in div.ui-layout-center, which I don't want. so, there is solution 1... but I would like the tabs div to fill all available space for current height is there a way to do it?

Comment: Maybe with some jquery? See third option. I have also struggled a lot with these problems: fixed size div side by side with percentual div. In the end, I was always reestructuring all the layout with all the divs percentual. Today, I just include some lib with a grid system, like bootstrap, and it does the trick for me. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: in fact, the `contentSelector` option of
jQuery layout did the trick.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mguijarr/288yaz15/1/